# Python Matplotlib - How to annotate y-axis values only on line plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, linegraph, yaxis

I was plotting 2 line graphs on a single plot, representing 2019 & 2020 data on vessel arrivals.

For each line graph,

The y-axis represents vessel arrival numbers

The x-axis represents the month, (March, April, May, etc..)

**However, I'm not sure how to get the y-axis values (Vessel Arrival Numbers) to appear on both line graphs.**

Does anyone know how?

My code and line graphs are featured below:

```
# Trendline comparison of the total number of vessel arrivals in 2019 & 2020

# Displaying all numbers to 0 decimal places
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.0f}".format

VESSEL_ARRIVALS_2019 = MARITIME_DATASET_2019["VESSEL ARRIVAL NUMBERS"]
VESSEL_ARRIVALS_2020 = MARITIME_DATASET_2020["VESSEL ARRIVAL NUMBERS"]

# Displaying the plotted figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (48, 20))
plt.xticks(fontsize = 20)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 20)
plt.plot(LIST_OF_MONTHS, VESSEL_ARRIVALS_2019, color = "blue", linewidth = 3,  label = "2019 NUMBER OF VESSEL ARRIVALS")
plt.plot(LIST_OF_MONTHS, VESSEL_ARRIVALS_2020, color = "red", linewidth = 3,  label = "2020 NUMBER OF VESSEL ARRIVALS")
plt.title("TOTAL NUMBER OF VESSEL ARRIVALS 2020 ON 2019 COMPARISON", fontsize = 32)
plt.legend(loc = "best", prop = {"size": 26})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) function. For example, like this.

```py
offset = 100 # adjust so it looks nice, but isn't on your line
for x, y in zip(LIST_OF_MONTHS, VESSEL_ARRIVALS_2019):
  plt.annotate(y, (x,y+offset))
```